# Getting error while creating NFT Auction Smart contract in v0.8.0.?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, nft

I am a newbie to solidity and its implementation and got an opportunity to work on a marketplace and I encountered this small version issue. I am working on a smart contract where an auction needs to refund the amount to the bidder after his/her bid is outbid by a higher bid. I got this code from Github which uses v0.7.0 of solidity whereas I want to create this smart contract using v0.8.0. It throws me an error on the 82nd line of the given below code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

contract Auction {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    uint256 public endTime; // Timestamp of the end of the auction (in seconds)
    uint256 public startTime; // The block timestamp which marks the start of the auction
    uint public maxBid; // The maximum bid
    address public maxBidder; // The address of the maximum bidder
    address public creator; // The address of the auction creator
    Bid[] public bids; // The bids made by the bidders
    uint public tokenId; // The id of the token
    bool public isCancelled; // If the the auction is cancelled
    bool public isDirectBuy; // True if the auction ended due to direct buy
    uint public minIncrement; // The minimum increment for the bid
    uint public directBuyPrice; // The price for a direct buy
    uint public startPrice; // The starting price for the auction
    address public nftAddress;  // The address of the NFT contract
    IERC721 _nft; // The NFT token

    enum AuctionState { 
        OPEN,
        CANCELLED,
        ENDED,
        DIRECT_BUY
    }

    struct Bid { // A bid on an auction
        address sender;
        uint256 bid;
    }

    // Auction constructor
    constructor(address _creator,uint _endTime,uint _minIncrement,uint _directBuyPrice, uint _startPrice,address _nftAddress,uint _tokenId){
        creator = _creator; // The address of the auction creator
        endTime = block.timestamp +  _endTime; // The timestamp which marks the end of the auction (now + 30 days = 30 days from now)
        startTime = block.timestamp; // The timestamp which marks the start of the auction
        minIncrement = _minIncrement; // The minimum increment for the bid
        directBuyPrice = _directBuyPrice; // The price for a direct buy
        startPrice = _startPrice; // The starting price for the auction
        _nft = IERC721(_nftAddress); // The address of the nft token
        nftAddress = _nftAddress;
        tokenId = _tokenId; // The id of the token
        maxBidder = _creator; // Setting the maxBidder to auction creator.
    }

    // Returns a list of all bids and addresses
    function allBids()
        external
        view
        returns (address[] memory, uint256[] memory)
    {
        address[] memory addrs = new address[](bids.length);
        uint256[] memory bidPrice = new uint256[](bids.length);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < bids.length; i++) {
            addrs[i] = bids[i].sender;
            bidPrice[i] = bids[i].bid;
        }
        return (addrs, bidPrice);
    }


    // Place a bid on the auction
    function placeBid() payable external returns(bool){
        require(msg.sender != creator); // The auction creator can not place a bid
        require(getAuctionState() == AuctionState.OPEN); // The auction must be open
        require(msg.value > startPrice); // The bid must be higher than the starting price
        require(msg.value > maxBid + minIncrement); // The bid must be higher than the current bid + the minimum increment

        address lastHightestBidder = maxBidder; // The address of the last highest bidder
        uint256 lastHighestBid = maxBid; // The last highest bid
        maxBid = msg.value; // The new highest bid
        maxBidder = msg.sender; // The address of the new highest bidder
        if(msg.value >= directBuyPrice){ // If the bid is higher than the direct buy price
            isDirectBuy = true; // The auction has ended
        }
        bids.push(Bid(msg.sender,msg.value)); // Add the new bid to the list of bids

        if(lastHighestBid != 0){ // if there is a bid
            address(uint160(lastHightestBidder)).transfer(lastHighestBid); // refund the previous bid to the previous highest bidder
        }
    
        emit NewBid(msg.sender,msg.value); // emit a new bid event
        
        return true; // The bid was placed successfully
    }

    // Withdraw the token after the auction is over
    function withdrawToken() external returns(bool){
        require(getAuctionState() == AuctionState.ENDED || getAuctionState() == AuctionState.DIRECT_BUY); // The auction must be ended by either a direct buy or timeout
        require(msg.sender == maxBidder); // The highest bidder can only withdraw the token
        _nft.transferFrom(address(this), maxBidder, tokenId); // Transfer the token to the highest bidder
        emit WithdrawToken(maxBidder); // Emit a withdraw token event
    }

    // Withdraw the funds after the auction is over
    function withdrawFunds() external returns(bool){ 
        require(getAuctionState() == AuctionState.ENDED || getAuctionState() == AuctionState.DIRECT_BUY); // The auction must be ended by either a direct buy or timeout
        require(msg.sender == creator); // The auction creator can only withdraw the funds
        address(uint160(creator)).transfer(maxBid); // Transfers funds to the creator
        emit WithdrawFunds(msg.sender,maxBid); // Emit a withdraw funds event
    } 

    function cancelAuction() external returns(bool){ // Cancel the auction
        require(msg.sender == creator); // Only the auction creator can cancel the auction
        require(getAuctionState() == AuctionState.OPEN); // The auction must be open
        require(maxBid == 0); // The auction must not be cancelled if there is a bid
        isCancelled = true; // The auction has been cancelled
        _nft.transferFrom(address(this), creator, tokenId); // Transfer the NFT token to the auction creator
        emit AuctionCanceled(); // Emit Auction Canceled event
        return true;
    } 

    // Get the auction state
    function getAuctionState() public view returns(AuctionState) {
        if(isCancelled) return AuctionState.CANCELLED; // If the auction is cancelled return CANCELLED
        if(isDirectBuy) return AuctionState.DIRECT_BUY; // If the auction is ended by a direct buy return DIRECT_BUY
        if(block.timestamp >= endTime) return AuctionState.ENDED; // The auction is over if the block timestamp is greater than the end timestamp, return ENDED
        return AuctionState.OPEN; // Otherwise return OPEN
    } 

    event NewBid(address bidder, uint bid); // A new bid was placed
    event WithdrawToken(address withdrawer); // The auction winner withdrawed the token
    event WithdrawFunds(address withdrawer, uint256 amount); // The auction owner withdrawed the funds
    event AuctionCanceled(); // The auction was cancelled


    
}
```

It would be of great help if anyone could suggest to me a good solution to the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hi AkhilTawdw! Unfortunately stackexchange doesn't number lines can you indicate what's the problematic line? Also can you show what's the exact error message?

Comment: Thank you for your response.This is the exact line     
                                                                                                          
   if(lastHighestBid != 0){ // if there is a bid
            address(uint160(lastHightestBidder)).transfer(lastHighestBid); // refund the previous bid to the previous highest bidder
        }           

TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address".

Comment: If you search for that error message you'll find a solution https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102346/transfer-only-available-for-objects-of-type-address-payable-not-address.