# Not able to transfer funds to the msg.sender

Tags: solidity, remix

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.9.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";
contract FundMe {
    using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    function fund() public payable {
        // $50
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * (10 ** 18);
        require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        
    }

    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256) {
      AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
      return priceFeed.version();  
    }

    function getPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
      AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
      (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
      return uint(answer*10000000000);
      //2,735.00457561
    }

    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) public view returns (uint256){
      uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
      uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice*ethAmount)/(1000000000000000000);
      return ethAmountInUsd; 
    }

    function withdraw() payable public {
      msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance); **//error**
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Why `withdraw` is payable? Is `msg.sender` a contract? How are you testing the `withdraw` function?

Comment: cause in withdraw function, I am trying to pay the sender whatever the balance is in my current contract. msg.sender is simply the address through which the contract is deployed.

Comment: You don't need the payable for sending payments, you need it when accepting payments. You haven't answered how the withdraw function is tested. Are you testing with ganache, remix, rinkeby, other testnet,... I see nothing wrong with the contract if msg.sender is an EOA it should work. A troubleshot option is to send more gas when calling withdraw.

Comment: ohh no actually I was watching tutorial freecodecamp.org and in that same code runs for them but not for me.
I am testing this on rinkeby testnet
It is showing following error:
TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address".

Comment: Sometimes if you search the error message it will point to an existing answer like this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102346/transfer-only-available-for-objects-of-type-address-payable-not-address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In latest solidity compiler when you transfer ether any address it must be payable address. You can make payable address just add payable keyword before the address.

Try this :

```
 function withdraw() public {
      payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this solves my problem, but can you also tell how to keep myself updated with these things?

Comment: Read the docs solidity.